# angular js custom filter does not update view or changes original array

Tags: angularjs, view, filter, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have created a custom filter to filter images that i get from MySql using php.
Then i pass the array into angular using encode and what i get is $scope.pics which has ID,pic_name and upload_date for each entry.

The custom filter works well as i can see it in the console . The problem is i am confused regarding how and where to call the filter .

I need to send the date range(that gets updated in the directive)into the filter

.

my directive :

```
app.directive('datepicker', function(){

return {
require: 'ngModel',
link : function(scope,element,attrs, ngModel){
    element.datepicker({
            dateFormat:'dd/mm/yy',
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            yearRange: '1950:2015',
            yearRange: "-100:+0",
            onSelect: function(dateText) {
              scope.$apply(function() {
                ngModel.$setViewValue(dateText);   
scope.helloFilter(scope.from,scope.to);//calling filter function- defined in controller  ,also from and to are my ng-models in my view for the two dates
              });
            },
          });   
    }
}});
```

my controller:
`app.controller('MyController',function($scope,$http,$filter) {`

```
.......


$scope.helloFilter = function(from,to){
return $filter('dateFilter')($scope.pics,from,to);
    };
```

my view: (its messy but i need help with just the date filter part !)

```
<div ng-repeat="pic in pics|filter:{pic_name:n}|filter : dateFilter ">
```

my filter:

```
app.filter('dateFilter', function(){    
    return function(arr,from,to) {

            var a =[];// to store upload dates from the recieved array 'arr'
            var arrNew = [];//array to store original array
            var picFilter = [];// to store filered array
            var i = 0;
            for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
            arrNew[i] = arr[i];//initialising to original array
            }
            if(from == null){ // if user doesnt provide start date
            from = moment("01011970","DD MM YYYY").format('MM DD YYYY');

            }

            f = moment((from),'DD MM YYYY').format('YYYY/MM/DD');//format input date to compare with MySql date
            t = moment((to),'DD MM YYYY').format('YYYY/MM/DD');


            var cnt=0;// to enter filtered data into array to be returned
            for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
                a[i] = arr[i].upload_date;//extracting date to compare
                con1 = moment(a[i],'YYYY MM DD').isAfter(f);

                con2 = moment(a[i],'YYYY MM DD').isBefore(t);


            if(con1 && con2){// if the dates in database lie between the range
            picFilter[cnt] = arr[i];//store the filtered array
             cnt++;
            }
            }

           if (picFilter.length>0){
                arrNew.length=0; 
           for(i=0;i<picFilter.length;i++){
            arrNew[i] = picFilter[i];//store filtered array
            }       
    } return arrNew;

    }
});`
```

The problem is :
The console shows the filter has worked perfectly .My issues :
1. Am i applying the date filter correctly?? (The 1st filter for pic_name works properly)

2.I dont know what happens to my returned array ? How do i get it reflected in my view?
3. If instead of

```
$scope.helloFilter = function(from,to){
return $filter('dateFilter')($scope.pics,from,to);
    };
```

I write :

```
$scope.helloFilter = function(from,to){
$scope.pics =  $filter('dateFilter')($scope.pics,from,to);
    };
```

My original array gets modified.

4. My model updates are not updated in the view. I also tried using **return true**.Then used $scope.$apply(),also $timeout !! none of them seem to work .

I am new to angularjs and I have a number of doubts related to its basics:-( Pls help !!